# Speeding up Sympy's solveset calculation for a large array of variables

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, sympy

I'm trying to create a parametrization of points in space from a specific point according to a specific inequality.

I'm doing it using `Sympy.solevset` method while the calculation will return an interval of the parameter `t` that represents all points between those in my dataframe.

Sadly, performing a `Sympy.solveset` over 13 sets of values (i.e 13 iterations) leads to execution times of over 20 seconds overall, and over 1 sec calculation time per set.

The code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import S
from sympy.solvers.solveset import solveset, solveset_real
import pandas as pd
import time

t=symbols('t',positive=True)
p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y=symbols('p1x p1y p2x p2y')

centerp=[10,10]
radius=5

data={'P1X':[0,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'P1Y':[3,2,1,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'P2X':[3,8,2,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'P2Y':[3,9,10,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'result':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

parameterized_x=p1x+t*(p2x-p1x)
parameterized_y=p1y+t*(p2y-p1y)

start_whole_process=time.time()

overall_time=0

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    
   parameterized_x.subs([[p1x,row['P1X']],[p2x,row['P2X']]])
   parameterized_y.subs([[p1y,row['P1Y']],[p2y,row['P2Y']]])
   expr=sqrt((parameterized_x-centerp[0])**2+(parameterized_y-centerp[1])**2)-radius
   
   start=time.time()

   df.at[index,'result']=solveset(expr>=0,t,domain=S.Reals)
   end=time.time()
   
   overall_time=overall_time+end-start
   
end_whole_process=time.time()
```

I need to know if there's a way to enhance calculation time or maybe there is another package that can preform a specific inequality over large quantities of data without having to wait minutes upon minutes.

Comment: The code as shown repeatedly calls solveset with the same input and so probably does not do what you wanted it to do.

Comment: I would get rid of anything to do with `pandas`.  Or at least convert the dataframe values to lists (or lists of lists).  Iteration in  `pandas` does not help with speed.  `sympy` isn't really intended for working large amounts of data.  For purely numeric work there are `numpy` and `scipy` solvers.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the answer, i tried to use optimize.minimize but those calculations return a value, while i need an interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one big mistake in your current approach than needs to be fixed first. Inside your for loop you did:

```py
parameterized_x.subs([[p1x,row['P1X']],[p2x,row['P2X']]])
parameterized_y.subs([[p1y,row['P1Y']],[p2y,row['P2Y']]])
expr=sqrt((parameterized_x-centerp[0])**2+(parameterized_y-centerp[1])**2)-radius
```

This is wrong: SymPy expressions cannot be modified in place. This leads your `expr` to be exactly the same for each row, namely:

```
# sqrt((p1x + t*(-p1x + p2x) - 10)**2 + (p1y + t*(-p1y + p2y) - 10)**2) - 5
```

Then, `solveset` tries to solve the same expression on each row. Because this expression contains 3 symbols, `solveset` takes a long time trying to compute the solution, eventually producing the same answer for each row:

```
# ConditionSet(t, sqrt((p1x + t*(-p1x + p2x) - 10)**2 + (p1y + t*(-p1y + p2y) - 10)**2) - 5 >= 0, Complexes)
```

Remember: every operation you apply to a SymPy expression creates a new SymPy expression. So, the above code has to be modified to:

```
px_expr = parameterized_x.subs([[p1x,row['P1X']],[p2x,row['P2X']]])
py_expr = parameterized_y.subs([[p1y,row['P1Y']],[p2y,row['P2Y']]])
expr=sqrt((px_expr-centerp[0])**2+(py_expr-centerp[1])**2)-radius
```

In doing so, `expr` is different for each row, as it is expected. Then, `solveset` computes different solutions, and it is much much faster.

Here is your full example:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers.solveset import solveset, solveset_real
import pandas as pd
import time

t=symbols('t',positive=True)
p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y=symbols('p1x p1y p2x p2y')

centerp=[10,10]
radius=5

data={'P1X':[0,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'P1Y':[3,2,1,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'P2X':[3,8,2,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'P2Y':[3,9,10,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'result':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

parameterized_x=p1x+t*(p2x-p1x)
parameterized_y=p1y+t*(p2y-p1y)

start_whole_process=time.time()

overall_time=0

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    px_expr = parameterized_x.subs([[p1x,row['P1X']],[p2x,row['P2X']]])
    py_expr = parameterized_y.subs([[p1y,row['P1Y']],[p2y,row['P2Y']]])
    expr=sqrt((px_expr-centerp[0])**2+(py_expr-centerp[1])**2)-radius
    df.at[index,'result']=solveset(expr>=0,t,domain=S.Reals)

end_whole_process=time.time()
print("end_whole_process - start_whole_process", end_whole_process - start_whole_process)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understood what i did wrong and since simpy's documentation is.. lacking to say the least, your answer helped me greatly!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please, mark this answer as the solution to your question. Also, I know very well that SymPy is not the easiest library to get familiar with, and the documentation is large and sparse. To address this issue, I wrote a book which I think it is very effective in explaining the fundamental concepts of SymPy to beginners. More info at this page: https://github.com/Davide-sd/sympy-book